# Web component setting property race condition

Tags: google-chrome, web-component, native-web-component

After a lot of digging I figured out sometimes if I set a property before the element is fully constructed, it overrides the setter. I found [this helpful code on google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices#lazy-properties):

> A developer might attempt to set a property on your element before its definition has been loaded. This is especially true if the developer is using a framework which handles loading components, inserting them into to the page, and binding their properties to a model.

```js
connectedCallback() {
  ...
  this._upgradeProperty('checked');
}

_upgradeProperty(prop) {
  if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    let value = this[prop];
    delete this[prop];
    this[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

Basically if the setter has been overriden by the property, it deletes the property, and then reapplies it so that the setter picks it up.

It works about 70% of the time. I can get it to work 100% with a nasty hack of setting a timeout:

```js
_upgradeProperty(prop) {
  if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    let value = this[prop];
    delete this[prop];
    setTimeout( () => this[prop] = value, 1); // <-- Hack here
  }
}
```

This feels really gross, is there any other way to upgrade the property after the element has actually got its getters/setting fully created and ready to go (`connectedCallback` is not cutting it). Is it a Chrome Bug?

Comment: More **digging** into when JS does what: [YoutTube:What the heck is the Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en) ``setTimeout`` is not a hack; it makes sure your code runs when the Event Loop is empty. All 60+ Tools available that make developing Web Components "easier" also add similar code _**to wait till the Event Loop is empty**_; with Promises, requestAnimationFrame or setTimeout. PS. I don't get it why you want to do a ``delete`` at all.

Comment: Thats that is a brilliant video, I've actually watched it before too! The reason it feels like a hack is because surely when connectedCallback is called, the setter for the property should exist. Setting a timeout just delays it until something else happens, that I don't know what, that then allows it to work. It's like there should an event "ConnectedAndFullyConstructedCallBack". With regards to why google deletes the property, my understanding to fix the MRO (method resolution order), so that it will access the setter before some constant that overrode the setter.

Comment: I embraced the `setTimeout`, I did not realise it was an accepted practise, thanks Danny!

Comment: Just as long as you understand what it does; don't abuse them, you will get yourself into trouble (been there, done that, still refactoring code) Lit [has 52](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Alit+setTimeout&type=code) in all code